# Rails "sub-environment" -- still production (or test, etc.) but different

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, architecture, development-environment, production-environment

How should we best handle code that is part of a single Rails app, but is used in several different "modes"?

We have several different cases of an app that is driven from the same data sources (MySQL, MongoDB, SOLR) and shares core logic, assets, etc. across multiple different uses.

Background/details:

**HTML vs REST API**
A common scenario is that we have HTML and REST interfaces.  These differences are handled through routing (e.g. `/api/v1/user/new` vs `/user/new`) -- with minor differences they provide the same functions.  This seems reasonably clean to me.

**Multi-tenant**
Another common scenario is that the app is "multi-tenant", determined mainly by subdomain of the URL, e.g. partner1.example.com and partner2.example.com (or query-string parameter for API customers) -- each has a number of features or properties that differ.  This is handled by a filter `ApplicationController` using data largely stored in a set of tenant-specific database tables with tenant-specific functionality encapsulated by methods.  This also seems reasonably clean to me.

**Offline Tasks**
One scenario is that a great deal of the data is acquired through a very large number of tasks, running pretty much continuously: feed loaders, scrapers, crawlers, and other tasks of this sort ... the kinds of things you would find in a search engine, which is a large part of what we do.  These tasks are launched on idle server instances and run periodically ... but are just `rake` tasks that are part of the app.

These tasks are characteristically different than our front-end code -- they update data, run calculations, do maintenance tasks and so on -- some tasks run for days (e.g. update 30M documents from an external web service).  In the end, these tasks create and keep fresh the core data that our front end app uses.

This one doesn't seem as clean to me, in particular, in some cases, these tasks are running and doing data updates at the same time as our application is using them, so occasionally need to defer to the front-end app when we're under peak loads.

**Major Variants of the App**
This last case is clearly wrong -- we have made major customizations of our app -- 15% or 20% different, by making branches and then running as an entirely separate app, sharing some of the core data sometimes, but using some of its own data other times.  We have mostly fixed this now, as it was, of course, untenable.

**OK, there's a question in here somewhere, right?**

So in particular for the offline tasks I feel like the app really needs to be launched in a "mode" or perhaps "sub-environment".  But we still have normal development, test, qa, demo, pre_release, production environments that have their own isolated data and other configuration parameters.  For each of these, we want to be able to run, develop, test and deploy the various "modes" of the application.

Can anyone suggest an appropriate architecture that is similar to the declarative notions of standard Rails environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If the number of modes is ever-increasing:

  Perhaps the offline tasks could be separated from the main app, into their own application (or a parent abstract task with actual tasks inheriting from it and deployed individually).
- If the number of modes is relatively small and won't be changing often:

  You could put the per-mode configuration into a config file, logically separate from the rest of the code. Then during the deployments, you would be able to provide a combination of (environment, mode,  set of hosts) and get a good level of control of your environments *while* using the same codebase.

Comment: Thanks @alexwriteshere -- in our case the number of modes is small and at least for now, it is impractical to separate applications, so I think your second bullet applies.  Is your suggestion that we kind of "include" the sub-environment files conditionally within the main environment?

Comment: The configuration would have the logic to create/include the objects that are different among sub-environments. It could be, as you said, done by pointing to different per-environment configuration files, or in general any configuration objects. For example, if you're configuring different sequences of offline tasks, those could be created in the configurations, and the main application would just execute them without knowing 'where' they came from. Does that make sense?

Comment: Perfect -- I like it.  Thanks very much -- great answer!